# How to write an android test which will verify my app hits all required apis

Tags: android, testing, proxy, android-espresso

I am heavily testing my application with unit tests and Espresso tests. My next step is to make sure my application hits all required apis. For that reason I am looking for a way to write a test, which will verify the api calls.
I would really appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is called a "unit test".  Unit tests are meant to test as many lines of code as possible regardless of UI.

Espresso tests are "instrumentation tests" (or "UI tests") intended to check if the app is responding to UI events correctly. They're not meant to verify the correctness of code, but the correctness of the functionality of the app as used by the user.

You can read about both at [the official documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/index.html). You'll find that unit tests are very different than instrumentation tests, and often harder to write because they require more engineering of your code to do correctly. You will likely have to "mock" the various parts of your application to make sure their APIs were called exactly as you expected.

Comment: Thank you @Doug ! I wrote most of the tests using Mockito and PowerMockito

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 main goal when I was writing api tests:
First is component based. The goal was to make sure each class / component makes an api call when certain criteria is met (for example calling an api A when onDestroy() is called)
Second, is to make sure the Apis are called is certain order for the analytics purposes.

The first step I achieved by using unit tests with injected mock objects via Mockito and PowerMockito. PowerMockito was used primarily to mock static methods and to make sure the methods were called at least n times.

For the second step, UI test could be used, since it runs the real application. I have implemented the helper class, which was recording the instances when api requests were made. The script in Espresso was validating the order of api calls by referring the helper class.